# python regex match querystring path

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a regex to match any path that contains `/?` to determine whether it is a querystring or not.

a sample string to be matched would be this: `/mysite/path/to/whatever/?page=1`

so far I thought this would match `re.match(r'/\?', '/mysite/path/to/whatever/?page=1')`

but it doesn't seem to be matching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using `re.match`. That function looks for matches at the beginning of the string. So, either you change your regexp to `'.*/\?'`, or use `re.search` instead.

Comment: `re.match` looks for matches *at the beginning of the string*, not complete matches.

Answer (score 3):

This code is already written for you. No need to reinvent the wheel:

```
 import urlparse
 print urlparse.urlparse('/mysite/path/to/whatever/?page=1')
```

http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#module-urlparse

Comment: +1, but you might want to do this with the regexp for Django's URL patterns, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a regular expression here. Just use  the `in` operator: `'/?' in the_string`.

---

The problem is that [`re.match`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.match) only looks at the beginning of the string. 
You could use [`re.search`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.search) instead, if you need the power of REs.